# How to make items in list clickable to open a url in the browser in IONIC

Tags: list, url, browser, ionic-framework

how can i make in ionic, whereby clicking an item on the list will cause it to open a variable link in the browser ?

in the example below, i have this website_url which cant be clicked

```
<ion-item collection-repeat="person in persons" class="item item-icon-right item-icon-left" href="{{person.website_url}}">

  <i class="icon icon ion-ios-person"></i>
    {{person.name}}
    <i class="icon ion-chevron-right"></i>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open an external url tapping on `<ion-item>` you can:

```
 <ion-item collection-repeat="person in persons" class="item item-icon-right item-icon-left" ng-click="openUrl(person.website_url)">
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.openUrl = function(external_url){
   window.open(external_url);
}
```